# debug *spanning-tree events* not showing up on 2960 router?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

Doing my ccna3 on lab 5.5.1 in packet tracer. question asks to do a *debug spanning-tree events* command on the 2960 router. this does not work. all routers have STP on.

the image below is a capture of the switch with the root bridge. this command does not work on any of the 3 switches and it is clearly written in the book to do this command on all 3.

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
S2#show spanning-tree 
VLAN0001
Spanning tree enabled protocol ieee
Root ID    Priority    32769
         Address     0001.643C.50E9
         This bridge is the root
         Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Bridge ID  Priority    32769  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 1)
         Address     0001.643C.50E9
         Hello Time  2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec
         Aging Time  20

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Fa0/1            Desg FWD 19        128.1    P2p
Fa0/2            Desg FWD 19        128.2    P2p
Fa0/6            Desg FWD 19        128.6    P2p
Fa0/11           Desg FWD 19        128.11   P2p
Fa0/18           Desg FWD 19        128.18   P2p



S2#debug ?
ip       IP information
sw-vlan  vlan manager



S2#debug spanning-tree events
          ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but, it's probably a limitation of Packet Tracer. I would assume from the output given that this isn't a router and actually a switch. In which case, it is a limitation.